# How to get Eulerchapternumbers in classicthesis to respect margins?

Tags: classicthesis

I am using classicthesis, and would like the chapter numbers to fall within the specified margins. I've used the geometry package to successfully set my margins for the text, but the chapter numbers are the only elements to lie outside these margins. In the image attached, this would pertain to the '1' being shifted slightly to the left so that it falls within the right margin. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

[image: Eulerchapternumber]

Edited to add code:

```
\documentclass[
    twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,%1headlines,
    footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,
    dottedtoc, % Make page numbers in the table of contents flushed right with dots leading to them
    BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt, % Binding correction, paper type and font size
    ngerman,american, % Languages, change this to your language(s)
    ]{scrreprt} 

\input{classicthesis-config}

\usepackage[inner=3.5cm, outer=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.5}


\makeatletter
\if@eulerchapternumbers
 \DeclareFixedFont{\chapterNumber}{U}{eur}{b}{n}{50}
\else
  \DeclareFixedFont{\chapterNumber}{T1}{pplj}{m}{n}{50}
\fi
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\frenchspacing % Reduces space after periods to make text more compact

\raggedbottom % Makes all pages the height of the text on that page

\selectlanguage{american} % Select your default language - e.g. american or ngerman

\pagenumbering{roman} % Roman page numbering prior to the start of the thesis content (i, ii, iii, etc)

\pagestyle{plain} % Suppress headers for the pre-content pages



\include{Chapters/Chapter_intro} % Chapter 1


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of your document?

Comment: Thanks! But we'll also need the `classicthesis-config.tex` file you are loading into your document to compile it correctly. Can you add it too, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a guess: You can redefine the chapter format in your preamble (after `\input{classicthesis-config}`) to

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
  {\relax}{\mbox{}\vskip-3\baselineskip\hfill\color{CTsemi}\chapterNumber\thechapter}{0pt}%
  {\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]%
```

Result:

[image]

Maybe you are using an older version of classicthesis: So if color `CTsemi` is defined, replace it by color `halfgray`.